# Django Rest Framework end points

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have a rather simple obj. It has three fields, a fk to a user, a title, and slug (created from the title). The slug field and user fk are unique together. I would like to create an API end point that has the urls base_url/api-model-name (retrieve's all objs), base_url/api-model-name/username (this is used for the create/list end point. This list only returns the obj that have a FK to a user). base_url/username/obj-slug - Used to update/retrieve the obj.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using DRF you can follow a pattern similar to this.

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'slug')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Foo


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from .models import Foo
from .serializers import FooSerializer


class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    permission_class = (IsAuthenticated, )
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

**routers.py**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import FooViewSet


router = DefaultRouter()

# registers viewset to url
router.register(r'foos', FooViewSet)
```

With this you would have the following endpoints:

`GET` `/foobars` - Retrieve all foobar objects add a pk and get a detail view

`POST` `/foobars` - Create foobar object `{"user": "", "title": "", "slug": ""}

For any other custom calls you can add additional methods to the main ViewSet via DRF decorators(detail_route, list_route). But following this pattern you can build robust API.